# i want to transfer data from angular js to servlet using GET method.saying null

Tags: javascript, java

i want to transfer data from angular js to servlet using GET method.saying null

form:

```
<form ng-submit="save()" class="contactForm" name="form" ng-hide="loaded">
     <input class="input" required="required" type="text" name="name" placeholder="your name" ng-model="name" /><br />
     <input class="input" required="required" type="text" name="number" placeholder="your phone" ng-model="number" /><br />

     <button class="btn green">OTP</button>
</form>
```

angular js:

```
   $scope.save = function () {
          $scope.loaded = true;
          $scope.process = true;
          $http({
              method : 'GET',
              url : 'http://localhost:8080/Panghal/sendOTP',
              contentType: 'application/json',
              data : JSON.stringify($scope.number)
  }).success(function () {
              $scope.success = true;
              $scope.process = false;
          });
        };


  }]);
```

SERVLET:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());
          String str = null;  
          StringBuffer sb = null;

         JSONObject jObj = null;
          BufferedReader br = null;
          try {
          br = request.getReader();
         sb = new StringBuffer();
          while ((str = br.readLine()) != null) {
             sb.append(str);
            }
              jObj = new JSONObject(sb.toString());
           String number = jObj.getString("data");
          /**** Preparing The Output Response ****/
           response.setContentType("text/html");
           response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
           response.getWriter().write("Welcome " + number + " !!");
```

Comment: <form ng-submit="save()" class="contactForm" name="form" ng-hide="loaded">
                <input class="input" required="required" type="text" name="name" placeholder="your name" ng-model="name" /><br />
               <input class="input" required="required" type="text" name="number" placeholder="your phone" ng-model="number" /><br />
                
                <button class="btn green">OTP</button>
            </form>

Comment: Those are form fields...why not use POST as your HTTP method?

Comment: You need to set `params` for a `$http.get()`, see docs. Also note that `$http.success` is deprecated

Comment: Take a look at the following for an example of how to POST form data from AngularJS to a Java Servlet - http://www.doublecloud.org/2013/09/angular-javascript-framework-interacting-with-java-servlet-backend/

Comment: i have a lots of code below this servlet code and it is hard for me to change this in POST instead of GET.

Comment: is it possible you can help me in GET method

Comment: i have changed to POST but it comes on parser object it going on exception
    try {
    br = request.getReader();
   sb = new StringBuffer();
    while ((str = br.readLine()) != null) {
       sb.append(str);
       System.out.println(str);
      }
     jp= new JSONParser();
    try
      {
  jObj = (JSONObject) jp.parse(sb.toString());
      } catch (Exception e) { 
        System.out.println(e);
       e.printStackTrace(); }
   
     
  String number = (String) jObj.get("number");
    /**** Preparing The Output Response ****/
     response.setContentType("text/html");